# How can I access GORM object properties in a GroovyScriptCommand?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.1

I used the Grails create-script command to create my own custom script for rendering source code artifacts based on a GORM domain object. I want to generate a command object that contains the properties of the domain object. I see the properties and methods on the GroovyScriptCommand and TemplateRenderer, but I can't tell how to get a reference to the domain object properties or how to render them in my scaffolding templates. I tried forClass(model.fullName) but it says ClassNotFounException. I also tried install-templates, but that command no longer installs templates that render any object properties.

Comment: no solution for you?

Comment: We did find a solution but it was a bit of a hack, not something I would recomend. I don't think there is a way to do it that is supported by this type of a script.